# VLOOKUP Excel analog in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataFrames.

df1:

```
index ID City         Region 2City
1     23 Moscow       Msk    
2     34 Obninsk      Msk    Msk
3     56                     Spb
4     17 Tula         Spb
```

df2:

```
index City   Office
1     Msk    Msk
2     Spb    Spb
3     Tula   Msk
4     Moscow Msk
```

I would like to get the following df:

```
index ID City         Region 2City Office
1     23 Moscow       Msk          Msk
2     34 Obninsk      Msk    Msk   Msk
3     56                     Spb   Spb
4     17 Tula         Spb          Msk
```

So it checks which `'office'` from df2 matches `'City'`, `'Region'`, `'2City'` from df1.

Also if I found `'office'` for `'City'`, I stop to search. So `'City'`column have the priority, then comes `'Region'`, then comes `'2City'`.

I know how to do this with 3 `for`, but I hope there is a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[23, 'Moscow', 'Msk', ''],
                    [34, 'Obninsk', 'Msk', 'Msk'],
                    [56, '', '', 'Spb'],
                    [17, 'Tula', 'Spb', '']],
                   columns=['ID', 'City', 'Region', '2City'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Msk', 'Msk'],
                    ['Spb', 'Spb'],
                    ['Tula', 'Msk'],
                    ['Moscow', 'Msk']],
                   columns=['City', 'Office'])

df = pd.concat([df1.loc[df1[x].isin(df2['City']), x] for x in ['City', 'Region', '2City']])
df1['Join'] = df.groupby(df.index).first()
output = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Join', right_on='City', how='right')
```

At this point, the `pandas.DataFrame` called "output" will contain a column called "Office" indexed appropriately to match with df1.  You could do something like:

```
df1['Office'] = output['Office']
```

And this will give you the DataFrame you requested plus the additional column "Join", which you can drop via:

```
df1.drop('Join', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The OP here wants basically to do three separate merges--one on each of the columns "City", "Region", and "2City" from `df1`.  It is therefore not easy to do this using basic `pandas.DataFrame` operations without some gymnastics.  I just hid the for loop in the list comprehension, but it's still there.

Comment: That one worked!
But only on my test DF.
Now, trying to do with my normal DF:)

Answer (score 1):

One generally does a VLOOKUP in Pandas using `join` (which defaults to a left join) or `merge` (where one must specify `how='left'`).

In your case, you are trying to lookup a value based on three columns.  One way to do this is by using `or` to take the first non-null value.

```
>>> (df1
     .assign(temp = [region or two_city or city 
                     for region, two_city, city in zip(df1.Region, df1['2City'], df1.City)])
     .merge(df2, how='left', right_on='City', left_on='temp', suffixes=['', '_'])
     .drop(['temp', 'City_'], axis=1))

   ID     City Region 2City Office
0  23   Moscow    Msk  None    Msk
1  34  Obninsk    Msk   Msk    Msk
2  56     None   None   Spb    Spb
3  17     Tula    Spb  None    Msk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two DataFrames with [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), but as I understand it, you actually want to merge on different columns in `df1`. A possible way to do this is by adding an extra column that takes the value of `'City'` if available (otherwise`'region'` or `'2City'`).

```
import pandas as pd

df1['Office'] = df1.City.fillna(df1.Region).fillna(df1['2City'])
df = pd.merge(df1, df2.reindex(columns='Office'), on='Office')
```

You don't specify if you have missing values in either DataFrame. If so, you can control their handling with the `how` argument to `pd.merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Without a `for` loop:

```
cols = ['City', 'Region', '2City']

df1[cols].applymap(lambda x: df2.set_index('City')['Office'].get(x)) \
         .apply(lambda row: row[row.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
```

I set `City` as the index for `df2` in order to lookup values with the `get` method. After looking up the values element-wise with `applymap`, I find the first valid answer with `first_valid_index`.

Comment: Tried it. Firstly it didn't want to deal with Nan, now I have the following mistake: `KeyError: (<class 'object'>, 'occurred at index 0')` and don't know what to do next